# Перенаправление с помощью ModRewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Хочу чтобы `site.ru/page.php` отображался, как `site.ru/page/`. Моя конструкция не работает:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /(.*).php /$1/
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, вам надо в обратную сторону.

Вы хотите, чтобы запрос браузера `site.ru/page/` внутри отобразился на `site.ru/page.php`. А ваш код говорит прямо противоположное: запрос от браузера на `.php` считается валидным, и превращается в `site.ru/page/` *на стороне сервера*.

`mod_rewrite` бежит на сервере.